# is it possible to send a control sequence to a terminal emulator using the keyboard

Tags: terminal, xterm, escape-characters, terminal-emulator

If you type `echo -e '\eZ'` and hit return in a shell running in an xterm, you'll see that the terminal emulator prints an obscure code `1;2c`. This seems to indicate that xterm interprets the VT100 control sequence `\eZ` (`ESC Z`, return terminal ID) and acts accordingly.

Now, if you press `ESC Z` in the same console, nothing happens. Does this mean that it is not possible to send control characters directly using the keyboard?

I'm not sure what is happening here, because pressing `CTRL s` (control flow) does stop the console output until you press `CTRL q`. So why does `CTRL s/q` work and not `ESC Z`?

Comment: can you please mark the answer below as correct if you are satisfied with it?

Answer (score 7):

VT100s responded to character sequences sent to them as *output*.  So echo'ing characters works because the terminal sees it as output.  Typing characters is input; the terminal will respond only if the characters are echoed by the receiving computer.  Your typical shell doesn't echo ESC, it interprets ESC as the prefix for some interactive input command.  Run `cat` and type ESC Z RETURN and you'll see the usual VT100 response.

Answer (score -2):

Also, you can press CTL-V on the keyboard usually first to tell the terminal that you want it to pass an ESC directly in instead of using it. Of course, you still have to get it echoed back to you, so doesn't necessarily help in this case, but instances where, say, you're editing a file in VIM and want to include an escape code, that's a convenient way to do so.

Comment: True, but this isn't what the question is about. The question asks how to send a command to the terminal, not how to input a control character literally.

Comment: @Gilles Umm, I think it is exactly about how to input a control character literally.  He wants to input a control character by pressing `ESC Z` in the same console he ran `echo -e '\eZ'` in, right?

Comment: @Nick No, as Kyle's answer explains, Ernest was trying to **output** ESC Z.